# <img> and <nav> in #globalnav not pushing themselves to max width

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive-design, navbar

I have a fixed header with a global navigation bar. The issue is that the logo and navigation menu in the `globalnav` are not pushing themselves to the max width of the container. The HTML code for the header is as follows:

```
<header id="globalnav-container">
    <div id="globalnav-wrapper">
        <div id="globalnav">
            <a href="/" aria-label="Home"><img id="globalnav-logo" src="/images/LogoBlack.png" alt="Logo Black"></a>
            <nav id="globalnav-menu" aria-label="Site navigation">
                <ul id="globalnav-menu-list">
                    <li class="globalnav-menu-list-item" id="globalnav-menu-list-item-web" title="Web Services Dropdown"><a href="#">Web</a></li>
                    <li class="globalnav-menu-list-item" id="globalnav-menu-list-item-mobile" title="Mobile Services Dropdown"><a href="#">Mobile</a></li>
                    <li class="globalnav-menu-list-item" id="globalnav-menu-list-item-desktop" title="Desktop Services Dropdown"><a href="#">Desktop</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

And the CSS code is as follows:

```
#globalnav-container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: default;
  height: 45px;
  transition: background 0.2s linear, height 0.2s linear;
}

#globalnav-wrapper {
  max-width: 980px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-left: 2rem;
  padding-right: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

#globalnav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#globalnav-logo {
  height: 16px;
  object-fit: contain;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
}

#globalnav-menu-list {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.globalnav-menu-list-item {
  padding: 0 10px;
}

#globalnav-menu {
  margin: 0;
}

@supports ((-webkit-backdrop-filter: saturate(180%) blur(20px)) or (backdrop-filter: saturate(180%) blur(20px))) {
  #globalnav-container {
    backdrop-filter: saturate(180%) blur(20px);
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: saturate(180%) blur(20px);
  }
}
```

I have set the `max-width` of the `globalnav-wrapper` to `980px` and centered it using `margin: 0 auto`. But the logo and navigation menu are not expanding to the full width of the container. How can I make them expand to the full width of the `globalnav-wrapper`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use`dispay:flex;` property to parent `<div>'s`. Only apply `dispay:flex;` property to `.globalnav`. Also if you want to use full width, Please remove `max-width:980px`.
Thank you.

```css
#globalnav-container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: default;
  height: 45px;
  transition: background 0.2s linear, height 0.2s linear;
}

#globalnav-wrapper {
  max-width: 980px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-left: 2rem;
  padding-right: 2rem;
}

#globalnav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content:space-between;
}

#globalnav-logo {
  height: 16px;
  object-fit: contain;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
}

#globalnav-menu-list {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.globalnav-menu-list-item {
  padding: 0 10px;
}

#globalnav-menu {
  margin: 0;
}

@supports ((-webkit-backdrop-filter: saturate(180%) blur(20px)) or (backdrop-filter: saturate(180%) blur(20px))) {
  #globalnav-container {
    backdrop-filter: saturate(180%) blur(20px);
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: saturate(180%) blur(20px);
  }
}
```

```html
<header id="globalnav-container">
    <div id="globalnav-wrapper">
        <div id="globalnav">
            <a href="/" aria-label="Home"><img id="globalnav-logo" src="/images/LogoBlack.png" alt="Logo Black"></a>
            <nav id="globalnav-menu" aria-label="Site navigation">
                <ul id="globalnav-menu-list">
                    <li class="globalnav-menu-list-item" id="globalnav-menu-list-item-web" title="Web Services Dropdown"><a href="#">Web</a></li>
                    <li class="globalnav-menu-list-item" id="globalnav-menu-list-item-mobile" title="Mobile Services Dropdown"><a href="#">Mobile</a></li>
                    <li class="globalnav-menu-list-item" id="globalnav-menu-list-item-desktop" title="Desktop Services Dropdown"><a href="#">Desktop</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Thanks, the only issue is that the image and nav are not centred horizontally anymore but I should be able to fix that 

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to mr. Hirtik for fixing my problem but for anyone who wants to know how to stop the `#globalnav` from touching the top and center it in the `#globalnav-container` with the current CSS, you can add the following styles to the `#globalnav` selector:

```
#globalnav {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 980px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100%;
}
```

This will make the `#globalnav` take up the full width of the `#globalnav-container`, with a maximum width of `980px`, and center it horizontally. The height property is set to `100%` to match the height of the `#globalnav-container`.